# UnboundLocalError when making sure the input is an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

```
def main():
    prompt = input('How many players? ')

    if prompt.isdigit():
        num_players = int(prompt)

    else:
        print('Invalid input!')
        main()

    print(num_players)

main()
```

If I enter a valid integer from the first time, everything works as expected, but if I enter a string first, the 'else' executes and I get prompted again, However, I get the UnboundLocalError when I actually input an integer. Any help is appreciated

Comment: In case of invalid input, you called `main()` again, and in *that* instance of the function, you did assign a value to the local variable `num_players`.  But you never set that variable in the original instance of `main()`, thus the error when trying to print it.  You really want to use a `while` loop here, rather than recursion, to repeat the user input until it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because this function is recursive. When you correctly enter an integer the second time, the innermost instance of `main` returns to the outer instance of `main` just after your `else` block. The next thing it tries to do is `print(num_players)` which worked fine in the inner instance but is unbound in the outer one.

Try moving the print inside the `if`

Note, it's not really the recursion that's the issue, it will still error if you remove the recursive call to `main` . The recursion just means you don't see the error until you finally enter an integer

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using recursion for this at all.

```
def main():
    while True:
        prompt = input('How many players? ')

        if prompt.isdigit():
            break

        print('Invalid input!')

    print(num_players)
```

There's no reason to use `isdigit` *and* `int`; you never use the `int` value, as it is immediately turned into a `str` again by `print`.

You can, however, use `int` *instead* of `isdigit` (especially if plan to use the `int` value later, rather than *just* printing it.

```
def main():
    while True:
        prompt = input('How many players? ')
        try:
            num_players = int(prompt)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(num_players)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code I posted here is a dumbed down version of the actual code where I actually use the num_players variable.
The reason I didn't do it as in your second version is because I did not want the user to input a float like 3.5.. Also, I wanted to minimize the number of checks and was trying to avoid having a try:except part and an isdigit() part. I ended up doing something like: 
if prompt not in [str(i + 1) for i in range(9)], which works just because I was given an upper limit in the original problem.

Comment: `int("3.5")` will raise an exception, rather than parsing the float *then* truncating like `int(3.5)` would.